# Как прочитать XML документ и получить значения c#

Tags: c#, xml

Есть XML такого вида:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/prog">
    <Resource name="3333/prog"
              auth="Container"
              dataSourceName="prog"
              connectionTestQuery="select 5"/>
    <Loader loaderClass="net.use" />
    <Environment name="com.34.validationEnabled"
                 type="java.lang.Boolean"
                 value="true"/>
    <Environment name="com.we.prog.key"
                 value=""
                 type="java.lang.String" />
    <Environment name="com.printerName"
                 value="ZDesigner LP 2824 Plus (EPL)"
                 type="java.lang.String" />   
    <Environment name="com.url"
                 value ="http://server1.me"
                 type="java.lang.String" />
    <Environment name="com.url"
                 value ="http://server2.me"
                 type="java.lang.String" />
    <Environment name="com.hardware.paperPrinter.printerName"
                 value="HP LaserJet"
                 type="java.lang.String" />
    <Environment name="spring.profiles.active"
                 value="security-office-main,barcode-printer-dummy,fiscal-printer-dummy,paper-printer-dummy"
                 type="java.lang.String" />
      <Environment name="com.Rate"
                 value="9600"
                 type="java.lang.String" />
</Context>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как в С# прочитать value="security-office-main,barcode-printer-dummy,fiscal-printer-dummy,paper-printer-dummy" и записать

Comment: с классом XDocument уже знакомы? Если нет, познакомьтесь/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43975677/c-sharp-parse-xml-into-object-with-child-elements

Comment: не могу сообразить. тут везде Environmnt и value, как с нужного Environmеnt достать value